# Android emulator controllers disappear

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-emulator, ubuntu-14.04, kde-plasma

I'm using Kubuntu 14.04, with KDE 4.13.3 and Android Studio 2.0 Beta 2. I created an emulator with the following specifications

[image: Emulator specifications]

The emulator run fine.

The emulator start with the controllers visible them, when I click on them they disappear.... is it a bug or am I missing something?

The Emulator controllers thet I'm talking about:

[image: Emulator controllers]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, here is the solution: Go to KDE System Settings -> Window Managment -> Window Rules -> New Rule

[image: sreenshot#1]
[image: sreenshot#2]

[Source](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=199170#c11)

Answer (score 1):

Same problem for me (same configuration)...

As a turn around you can still use keyboard shortcuts.
In example :

- F7 ==> power button
- home ==> home button
- esc ==> back
- ctrl+F11 ==> rotate
- ...

All shortcuts can be find here : https://www.shortcutworld.com/shortcuts.php?l=en&p=win&application=Android-Emulator

Nicolas.

Comment: Note this is an official bug  on android issues, see [issue 199170](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Status%20Priority%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars%20Reporter%20Opened&groupby=&sort=&id=199170)